# Is it possible to translate image Title and Alt fields and sync images between tranlations?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

Since it would be much easier to manage site with images synchronized. But I have to translate Title fields too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about images uploaded to the site by users and administrators (and *not* static images that are integrated into the site as parts of a theme or a module), *and* you're talking about Drupal's core [locale](https://drupal.org/taxonomy/term/34342) framework for translation and the built-in extensions available through the [i18n](https://drupal.org/project/i18n) module, the answer is "no".

Like everything else, it is of course possible to create a custom module to manage translation of image title fields (preferably as a submodule of some popular image management module), but I am not aware of anything like that already exists.